# Good naming convention for functions and methods which may modify (write back to) a parameter

Tags: java, function, naming-conventions, methods, ref-parameters

I need to find a good and understandable naming-scheme for routines which deal with "value arrays" *(I've written something similar to C++'s `valarray` in Java, with some optimizations for primitive types in mind)*.

I know that the main categorization of routines is made between:

- functions (they may take parameters and must return something)
- methods (they may take parameters and don't return anything)

For performance reasons, I allow to define not only functions/methods which threat their parameters as readonly, but also functions/methods which may modify their first parameter.

*So that one can not only do this... :*

```
ValArrayInt a=..., b=...;
// "apply" treats "a" and "b" as readonly
ValArrayInt temp = ValArrays.apply(adder, a, b); // temp = a + b
a = temp;
```

*... but also this:*

```
ValArrayInt a=..., b=...;
// "apply" modifies "a"
a.apply(adder, b); // a += b
```

**Please, suggest a naming scheme for these kinds of routines:**

- **functions** which treat all parameters as **readonly**
- **functions** which **may modify** their first parameter
- **methods** which treat all parameters as **readonly**
- **methods** which **may modify** their first parameter

I have thought of something like ModifyingMethod, NonModifyingMethod, or similar, but I think those names are not straightforward enough, and too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the word "update" in a method name to indicate that one or more of the parameters will be updated as a result. For ex:

```
updateClaimWithPolicyDetails(Claim c, PolicyCriteria pc, String identifier)
```

You can reasonably deduce that this method *might* update the Claim object. Then if a user wants to know more he can dig into the javadoc

For functions that return something and also update parameters something like "updateAndGet" could be used.

```
public Policy updateClaimAndGetPolicy(Claim c, PolicyCriteria pc, String identifier)
```

From this you can deduce that one is updating the Claim and returning a policy (the claim may be already updated for the policy).

If the word updateXXX is not used in a method then you should assume that all params are readonly. If you have two updatable parameters then you could say

```
updateClaimAndPolicyCriteria(Claim C, PolicyCriteria pc, String junkParam)
```

The above can tell you that both claim and policy criteria will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

It may be complex to encode this info into the method name.

On the other hand this info **must** exist on the documentation of the method (e.g on the Javadoc) by explicitly stating the sideeffects of the method.

Comment: The problem is: most users look into the API docs only when the method name (and/or parameters) are not obvious enough.

Answer (score 0):

I like the above answer of pre-pending update or modify. However, this should really be a function of documentation to describe what calling a function does and how it affects the parameters. However, usually you don't want to modify parameters passed to a function, thought there are cases (like Collections.sort) where you want to do this to prevent a copy. Also, make sure to use immutable objects where appropriate instead of always using some stupid java bean class with all public getters and setters.